# Installing the right version of PyGame

Tags: pygame

I've been trying to install PyGame for Python, and can't seem to get Python to recognize that it's there.  I use Python 3.3, and have a 64-bit Windows computer, but that's really all I know.  The PyGame website has piles of different versions of the installer, but I can't seem to find the right one.  Either they let me install it but then starts spitting errors (basically saying the module doesn't exist, when it does), or I get this sort of set-up program that keeps saying it's not in my "registry".

Comment: Can you post your error messages verbatim?

Comment: Do you have 64bit python as well? I'm not sure it's supported. However, try this pygame version: http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi

Answer (score 1):

Pygame only works for 32-bits version of Python, so that's the reason it didn't find your Python installation on the registry.

In the Downloads section, the following can be read:

> windows 64bit users note: use the 32bit python with this 32bit pygame.

http://pygame.org/download.shtml

And I also recommend you to use Python 2.7 for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Compatibility with what? Legacy code of his, third party libraries? For new code with a Python deployment you control, I see no point in targetting Python 2 if your libraries and code can target Python 3.

Comment: Compatibility between the framework and the Python version. The difference between the versions may cause some unforeseen bug in your program, although I've never seen anything happen yet.
Also, Python 2 is just powerful enough to the point that I think Python 3 is rather unnecessary, without mentioning the fact that there are more complementary software supporting 2.x than 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used pygame on 64-bit Windows with both Python2.7 and Python3.3.

I used the installers from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Choose the appropriate one to match your Windows and Python versions, in your case: pygame-1.9.2pre.win-amd64-py3.3.‌exe